# Feel my heart beating even when resting, happened after drinking

Tags: heartbeat

I'm 15 years old and a male from Sweden. For the last 2 werks I've been starting to party and drink with my friends. But i have never gotten "drunk" more preferably "a bit happy". But for 3 days ago i drank possibly a bit too much, and got quite groggy and unresponsive. The other day when i woke up i felt my heart beating hard, and  i occasionally feel my heart beating without touching it with my hands. It isnt beating fast but harder, i'm an "athlete" and my fat percentage is quite low, so it might br easier to feel it.

I also read somewhere that the heart has to work even harder during an hangover to eviscerate/clean toxic from the blood. I stayed  away from alcohol the whole day, but drank a beer and a little liquor in the night with my friends. But i didnt effect me much. Now 2 days after my heart is still beating hard. When I inhale, it hurts a bit in my heart/chest. 
Is this dangerous, should i consider contacting a doctor or should I wait 2-3 days? Edit** My dad also has a high heart pressure
Thanks

Comment: Chest pain must never be ignored, even at the age of 15. It is not normal and can often indicate a serious medical problem. Requests for personal medical advice are prohibited here, so the only advice we can offer you is to see a doctor ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend seeing a doctor, although to put your mind at ease, I can tell you both from research and heavy personal experience that [palpitations](http://www.webmd.com/heart-disease/guide/what-causes-heart-palpitations) can also be caused by *many* things including stress, anxiety, depression, *sleep deprivation*, *dehydration* (possibly chronic), poor nutrition, caffeine, nicotine, *alcohol*, other drug side effects, etc. While scary, usually they aren't life threatening, but always best to see a doctor to be safe when it comes to your heart.

Answer (score -2):

I am a bit older than you (22), and I have had the same problem. One night, during new years I was binge drinking with friends and the next morning I felt my heart pounding with some light chest pains. The pounding has continued up to this day, but it is a lot lighter and I don't really notice it until I focus on it or lay down to sleep. The best advice I can give you is:
1) See your doctor to have your mind put at ease
2) Drink lots of water 
3) Avoid alcohol, caffeine and drugs ( I still drink alcohol, it's hard not to when all our friends are but I limit and try not to go overboard or I end up feeling like shit)
4) Remind yourself you're fine and try to exercise a bit.

Comment: You have not had the same problem. You had the same symptom. But while you seem to have no negative consequences, he might.